# Field with ListProperty(db.Key) is skipping in form created using wtforms.ext.appengine.db import model_form?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, wtforms

I am using model_form to create form automatically from the App Engine model. It works fine, but the created form doesn't include ListProperty() field.
Code snippet:

In models.py:

```
class Team(db.Model):

    name = db.StringProperty()
    members = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

in views.py:

```
def test_app():

    form = model_form(Team)
    app.logger.debug("form :" + str(dir(form)))
    return render_template("some_template.html")
```

dir(form) is not showing field 'members' which is a ListProperty(). I can't use 'form.members' in templates because form doesn't have 'members' attribute.

I see in http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.3/ext.html doesn't have equivalent 'Field' for ListProperty. How to handle these kind of models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WTforms doesn't provide equivalent 'Field' for ListProerty of App Engine and model_form is skipping 'members' field. So, some how we have store 'db.Key' instances in 'members' datastore field. After spending many hours on this issue, finally i was able to store 'db.Key' instances in members field. Code snippets is as follows:

models.py:

```
class Team(db.Model):
    members = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
```

Since members stores 'db.Key' instance of all available members. Form displayed should have multiple choice field, so that user can select multiple members. I used WTforms to do that.

forms.py:

```
class TeamForm(wtf.Form):
    members = wtf.SelectMultipleField('Members', validators=[validators.Required()])
```

views.py:

```
class create_team():
    form = TeamForm()
    form.members.choices = [(u.key(), u.name) for u in Member.all().order('name')]
    return render_template("create_team.html", form=form)
```

HTML just renders form fields.Now, If you try to save the form you would get error "'sdjfsjdfks23746jhew874' is not a valid choice for this field". I digged into WTforms code, open wtforms/fields/core.py.

```
class SelectMultipleField(SelectField):
    """ 
    No different from a normal select field, except this one can take (and
    validate) multiple choices.  You'll need to specify the HTML `rows`
    attribute to the select field when rendering.
    """
    widget = widgets.Select(multiple=True)

    def iter_choices(self):
        for value, label in self.choices:
            selected = self.data is not None and self.coerce(value) in self.data
            yield (value, label, selected)

    def process_data(self, value):
        try:
            self.data = list(self.coerce(v) for v in value)
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            self.data = None

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        try:
            self.data = list(self.coerce(x) for x in valuelist)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError(self.gettext('Invalid choice(s): one or more data inputs could not be coerced'))

    def pre_validate(self, form):

        if self.data:
            values = list(c[0] for c in self.choices)
            for d in self.data:
                if d not in values:
                    raise ValueError(self.gettext("'%(value)s' is not a valid choice for this field") % dict(value=d))
```

As you can see pre-validate function was throwing that error. self.choices contains all the choices you have provided in views.py which contains [(db.Key instance, member name), ...]. db.Key instance is the one that will be sent to the html form but in the form of unicode. Hence, self.data contains list of unicode value for each of the db.Key instance. That's why

```
if d not in values:
```

this condition is satisfied and hence the exception is raised. To make it work I changed pre-validate() function as follows(I don't know what else do to)

```
def pre_validate(self, form):

    if self.data:
        values = list(unicode(c[0]) for c in self.choices)
        for d in self.data:
            if d not in values:
                raise ValueError(self.gettext("'%(value)s' is not a valid choice for this field") % dict(value=d))
```

Now, while storing form date in the datastore in views.py funtion. Use this:

```
members = [db.get(data).key() for data in form.members.data if data]
```

Converting unicode to 'db.Key' instance. Hope it helps someone, If there is any better way please let me know.